# how is a khandit shivling revived again and restored

Tags: shiva, shiva-lingam

very soon gyanvapi temple will be restored.
what are the procedures as per shastras to revive nd reinstall a khandit or abandaoned shivling like the one there is present at gyanwapi well?

plz explain the process to revive shivling or is it considered always revived due to jyotirlingaa it being

Comment: Sanjay Dixit in Jaipur Dialogues current TV programs has mentioned about construction parts of the central Ling.. Bottom third Brahma square section. Central Vishnu section octagonal, upper one third  cylindrical / ellipsoidal represents Shiva's part . Prana Pratishta is by Mantras for new/installed  Linga. Not sure about repair procedure.  May be mentioned in  Agama sastras. Lord Ganesha is worshipped with a (broken)  khanditha tooth.

Comment: can plz share videos?